# background image wont show up in the rails app i'm working on

Tags: css, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, background-image

I'm trying to do some front-end design work in a rails app and I can't seem to get the background image to show up in my hero section! I think it might have to do with that he's using postgresql and I don't have in on my system.

Here's my css/scss

```
/*************************HOME PAGE*************************/

body {
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
}

 .head { 
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff; 
    border-bottom-width: 1px; 
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    padding-top: 12px;
 }

.headtext {
    font-size: 200%;
    padding-top: 67px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hero {
    background: url('heroimage.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
```

I've ran the "bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production" 
and the "rake assets:precompile" command to see if it helps and it still doesn't seem to be showing up. There was also a problem with installing the 'pg gem' when I bundled installed. The image is in the app/assets/images directory. Sorry for my ignorance! Thanks!

Comment: Can you see it in development mode? Is this a Rails 4 app?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error on the image? I am not entirely sure that your path is correct for the image.  if it's inside app/assets/images, see if you're getting a 404 and what path it's looking for and let us know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the provided SASS helper methods, Rails/Sprockets will intelligently look for the image in `app/assets`, `vendor/assets`, `public`, etc.

Your options are: `image-url("heroimage.png")`, `image-path("heroimage.png")`, `asset-url("heroimage.png")` or `asset-path("heroimage.png")`.

(You can also use ERB helpers if you need to - see the link to the docs below.)

[Here's](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-sass) a link to the docs.

Comment: Thank you so much! Totally helped!

Comment: @pdoherty926 what if none of the above options work? I have tried all the options. image is in app/assets/images folder.

Comment: @doyz I'd recommend creating a question of your own and providing some more context.